# Cannot get child nodes of a specific type that contain a specific text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Using the code below, I can receive all the `<job>` elements in my Xml. However, when I try to search for jobs that have a child called `<Name>` and their text equals `"receiverjob"`, the `SelectNodes()` method returns zero even though the job exists.

```
XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
dom.Load(textBoxFilePath.Text);
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(dom.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData");
XmlNodeList jobElements = dom.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("descendant::d:job[name=receiverjob]", nsManager);
```

**Xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file contains job definitions in schema version 2.0 format -->
<job-scheduling-data version="2.0" xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <processing-directives>
    <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
  </processing-directives>
  <schedule>
    <job>
      <name>receiverjob</name>
      <group>receivergroup</group>
      <job-type>Quartz.Server.ArgumentReceiverJob, Quartz.Server</job-type>
      <job-data-map>
        <entry>
          <key>receivedargument</key>
          <value>hamburger</value>
        </entry>
      </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <simple>
        <name>argumentreceiverJobTrigger</name>
        <group>argumentreceiverGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>receiverjob</job-name>
        <job-group>receivergroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>
    <job>
      <name>batchjob</name>
      <group>batchGroup</group>
      <job-type>Quartz.Server.BatchJob, Quartz.Server</job-type>
      <durable>true</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Trigger2</name>
        <group>DEFAULT</group>
        <job-name>batchjob</job-name>
        <job-group>batchGroup</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0/15 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
    <job>
      <name>jobnamexxx</name>
    </job>
    <job>
      <name>jobnamexxx</name>
    </job>
    <job>
      <name>jobnamexxx</name>
    </job>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an XPath expert, but I suspect your query now is trying to find jobs where the `name` element is equal to a `receiverjob` element. I suspect you want something like this:

```
"descendant::d:job[name/text()='receiverjob']"
```

It's also possible that you need to qualify the `name` element to be in the right namespace:

```
"descendant::d:job[d:name/text()='receiverjob']"
```

I would *strongly* consider using LINQ to XML instead, however, where it would be really simple (IMO):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(textBoxFilePath.Text);
XNamespace ns = "http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData";
var jobs = doc.Descendants(ns + "job")
              .Where(x => (string) x.Element(ns + "name") == "receiverjob");
```

I'm uncertain about the XPath syntax, but I'm confident about the LINQ to XML version - which in itself is a mark of the benefit of that solution, IMO. (Of course, to an XPath expert who hadn't used LINQ to XML, the opposite might be true.)

Comment: Thank you! Your XPath worked. I still don't know why I should mention this prefix everywhere. I honestly need to learn LINQ to XML but I spent some time last week learning XPath and if it returns the query results I want by writing one line of code, then I think it is worth it. But you are right, I should better myself in LINQ as well.

Comment: @Pedram: The prefix is to specify that you want the element in that namespace... which it *is* due to namespace inheritance in XML. Note that the four lines I've presented completely replace the five lines you presented... and if you want to put the query on one line, you can do that too... I just think this way is more readable :)

Comment: Hard to disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the prefix on the `name` element as well and you need to quote the string literal: `"descendant::d:job[d:name = 'receiverjob']"`.

Comment: Your answer is correct as well Martin, But I am afraid Jon Skeet answered before you, so I have to choose him.